# How to collect list from lambda expression

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am writing a method which will return a list of regiondata, i am doing in following manner but getting error

```
@Override
    public List<RegionData> getAllRegionsForDeliveryCountries()
    {
        final List<RegionData> regionData = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> countriesIso = getCountryService().getDeliveryCountriesIso();
        regionData = countriesIso.stream().map(c->i18nFacade.getRegionsForCountryIso(c)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return regionData;
    }
```

I am getting error on

```
type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<RegionData>> to List<RegionData>
```

on line regionData = countriesIso.stream().map(c->i18nFacade.getRegionsForCountryIso(c)).collect(Collectors.toList());

The function i18nFacade.getRegionsForCountryIso(c) is returning a list of region data, I want to combine these lists into single list.
I tried with lambda but unable to do so.

Comment: [A note on styling.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OpAgZvYXLQ&t=4632)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use flatMap with stream.

```java
regionData = countriesIso.stream()
    .flatMap(c -> i18nFacade.getRegionsForCountryIso(c).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or `regionData = countriesIso.stream().map(i18nFacade::getRegionsForCountryIso).flatMap(List::stream).toList()`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element
>   of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by
>   applying the provided mapping function to each element.

```
regionData = countriesIso
               .stream()
               .flatMap(c -> i18nFacade.getRegionsForCountryIso(c)
               .stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to be using `Stream#flatMap` instead of `Stream#map`.

Comment: This is basically correct but not very helpful. Please elaborate.